# downgrade image by factor of2

Tags: c++, image

I am given a stub to implement. This would downgrade an image by factor of 2.input is the image array of input image. output is the output array of output image. output_height and output_width are height and width of output image. While downgrading each 2X2 block is replaced by a single pixel where pixel value is the maximum value in the2X2 block. The arrays are in row major format. My code is as follows-

```
int input_index_row=0;
int output_index_row=0;
int input_index_column=0;
int output_index_column=0;
//unsigned char max(unsigned char* a,int width)

void print_input(unsigned char*input,int input_width,int input_height)
{
    cout<<"input->"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<input_width*input_height;i++)
    {
        if(i%input_width==0)
        {
            cout<<"::::";
        }
        cout<<(int)input[i]<<"-";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void print_output(unsigned char*output,int output_width,int output_height)
{
    cout<<"output->"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<output_height*output_width;i++)
    {
        cout<<(int)output[i]<<"-";
    }
    cout<<endl;

}


unsigned char* loc(unsigned char*a,int i,int j,int width)
{
    return a+width*i+j;
}


unsigned char max_loc(unsigned char*a,int i,int j,int width)
{
    unsigned char* res=0;
    res=loc(a,i,j,width);
    unsigned char max= *res;
    res=loc(a,i,j+1,width);
    if(max<*res)
    {
        max = *res;
    }
    res= loc(a,i+1,j,width);
    if(max<*res)
    {
        max = *res;
    }
    res= loc(a,i+1,j+1,width);
    if(max<*res)
    {
        max = *res;
    }
    cout<<"max="<<(int)max<<endl;
    return max;
}



void downgrade(unsigned char *input,unsigned char* output,int output_width,int output_height)
{
    /*int output_width=4;
    int output_height= 4;*/

    int input_width=output_width*2;
    int input_height=output_height*2;

    /*unsigned char *input= new unsigned char[input_width*input_height];
    for(unsigned char i=0;i<input_width*input_height;i++) input[i]=i;
    print_input(input,input_width,input_height);

    unsigned char* output = new unsigned char[output_width*output_height];*/
    unsigned char* result;
    while(input_index_row<input_height)
    {
        while(input_index_column<input_width)
        {
            result = loc(output,output_index_row,output_index_column,output_width);
            *result = max_loc(input,input_index_row,input_index_column,input_width);
            input_index_column+=2;
            output_index_column++;
        }
        input_index_row+=2;
        output_index_row++;
        input_index_column=0;
        output_index_column=0;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    print_input(input,input_width,input_height);
    print_output(output, output_width,output_height);
}
```

But I am getting corrupted output image
It is a jpeg image.I need to convert to greyscale.

Comment: What kind of image is it? At first glance I suppose it could work for a monochrome image, but for the usual rgb(a) images (or argb, or rgb... there's a wide variety) simply taking every 2nd char won't work, since in an rgba image you will get a result of rbrbrbrb, and for a rgb image you will get rbgrbgrbg etc... The step width has to be the width of one color element, not simply one char.
Btw, for dealing with images I usually use a specialized lib, like Freeimage. Saves a lot of hassle.

Comment: I hope your program only calls `downgrade` once and then exits.

Answer (score -1):

Most image formats use data compression to reduce the size of the image. If the image data is valid, it should contain a header that has information about the type of image, and it's format. You need to determine the image format from the header or you will corrupt the data.

Here is an example of .tga file format (Partial) You can look it up easily.

[image]

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it's completely irrelevant - the input image is stated to already be in memory.